# How to make plotly express figure taller in notebook cell?

Tags: python, plotly, google-colaboratory

From this tiny project https://github.com/bkontonis/Plot-PostCodes-on-Interactive-Map-Using-Python/blob/master/Plot%20on%20Map.ipynb

```py
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(post_df, lat="latitude", lon="longitude", zoom=3, height=300)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Draws a world map using plotly in the cell's result space.

How can I make this figure three times as tall in Google colab?

I tried

```py
from IPython.display import Javascript
display(Javascript('''google.colab.output.setIframeHeight('1000px')'''))
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(post_df, lat="latitude", lon="longitude", zoom=3, height=300)
fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="open-street-map")
fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Which does seem to correctly make the cell taller (only up to 1000px though, I can't get it to do more sadly)

But the figure is only as tall as 500px it seems, there's a lot of blank space underneath.

Comment: That is because you left the `height=300` in the call to `px.scatter_mapbox()` ?